# How do I convert strings starting with numbers to numeric data in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, string, types, type-conversion

Given the following XML:

```
<table>
  <col width="12pt"/>
  <col width="24pt"/>
  <col width="12pt"/>
  <col width="48pt"/>
</table>
```

How can I convert the width attributes to numeric values that can be used in mathematical expressions? So far, I have used `substring-before` to do this. Here is an example template (XSLT 2.0 only) that shows how to sum the values:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:text>Col sum: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(
        for $w 
        in col/@width 
        return number(substring-before($w, 'pt'))
     )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now my questions:

- Is there a more efficient way to do the conversion than `substring-before`?
- What if I don't know the text after the numbers? Any way to do it without using regular expressions?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. 

To decide which answer fits my criterion best, I've created a benchmark: a table with 10000 columns, running the stylesheet 1000 times in saxon with the -repeat option and taking note of the average execution time of the transformation.
The outcome was as follows: AakashM solution is the fastest (110ms) but requires all characters in the attribute to be known beforehand. My solution (substring-before) comes second in the efficiency category (115ms). When the text is unknown, Dimitre's solution is faster (125ms) than using regexes (130ms).

Comment: These numbers also show that this is not the right place to optimize the stylesheet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242725/extracting-number-int-decimal-from-a-string-with-xslt-1-0/2245231#2245231) from [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) that provides a very clever XPATH solution that doesn't use regex:

```
translate(., translate(.,'0123456789', ''), '')
```

It uses the nested translate to strip all the numbers from the string, which yields all other characters, which are used as the values for the wrapping translate function to strip out and return just the number characters.

Applied to your template:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:text>Col sum: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(
        for $w 
        in col/@width 
        return number(translate($w, translate($w,'0123456789', ''), ''))
     )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is horrible, but depending on just how much you know about the potetntial set of non-numeric characters, you could strip them with `translate()`:

```
translate("12jfksjkdfjskdfj", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "")
```

returns

```
"12"
```

which you can then pass to `number()` as currently.

(I said it was horrible. Note that `translate()` is case sensitive, too)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 is there a reason why you want to avoid using regex?

The most simple solution would probably be to use the **[replace function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)** with a regex pattern to match on any non-numeric character and replace with empty string.:

```
replace($w,'[^0-9]','')
```